# Showing Jacobi identity for Poisson Bracket

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, symplectic-geometry

We were given the following problem: show that $[A,[B,C]] + [B,[C,A]] + [C,[A,B]] = 0$ where $[A,[B,C]]$ et cetera are Poisson brackets. As I understand it this is a poisson bracket (where $\mathcal{H}$ is the Hamiltonian): $$\sum_i \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_i} \frac{\partial \mathcal H}{\partial p_i} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial p_i} \frac{\partial \mathcal H}{\partial q_i} \right)$$

Well and good, that means, for example, that $[B,C]$ would be: $$
\sum_i \left(\frac{\partial B}{\partial q_i} \frac{\partial C}{\partial p_i} - \frac{\partial B}{\partial p_i} \frac{\partial C}{\partial q_i} \right)
$$
and $[A,[B,C]]$ would be $$\sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial A}{\partial q_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}\left(\frac{\partial B}{\partial q_i} \frac{\partial C}{\partial p_i} - \frac{\partial B}{\partial p_i} \frac{\partial C}{\partial q_i} \right)-\frac{\partial A}{\partial p_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial q_j}\left(\frac{\partial B}{\partial q_i} \frac{\partial C}{\partial p_i} - \frac{\partial B}{\partial p_i} \frac{\partial C}{\partial q_i} \right)$$

Multiplying this all out and taking the derivatives 
$$\sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial A}{\partial q_j}\left(\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial p_j p_i}\frac{\partial B}{\partial q_i} + \frac{\partial^2B}{\partial p_j q_i}\frac{\partial C}{\partial p_i}  - \frac{\partial^2 B}{\partial p_i p_j} \frac{\partial C}{\partial q_i} + \frac{\partial B}{\partial p_i} \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial q_i} \right)-\frac{\partial A}{\partial p_j}\left(\frac{\partial B}{\partial q_i} \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial p_i q_j} + \frac{\partial^2 B}{\partial q_i q_j} \frac{\partial C}{\partial p_i} - \frac{\partial^2 B}{\partial p_i q_j} \frac{\partial C}{\partial q_i} + \frac{\partial B}{\partial p_i } \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial q_i q_j}\right)$$

its hard to keep track of this. So I figure that there has to be an easier way to do this, at least notation-wise. I have seen some other notations but there's never any explanation and I might be able to follow them if I understood what I was seeing.

So for non-mathematicians who are seeing this in a physics class, if there are any suggestions as to a better notational system that would be most appreciated.

I'm not really even sure what tags to put on this...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jacobi's identity for bracket product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754012/jacobis-identity-for-bracket-product)

Comment: It suffices to show that the Hamiltonian vector field of the Poisson bracket of two functions is the Lie bracket of the Hamiltonian vector fields of the two functions. You can then apply the Jacobi identity for the Lie bracket of vector fields (as cited by @EthakkaappamwithChai).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The algebra is lengthy, and I don't know any way around it, but for clarity, let's use this notaion:
$$
u_x=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \text{and}\ u_{xy}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x\partial y}
$$
Since all $p_i$ and $q_i$ are independent for each value of $i$, let's constarain our focus to the problem of one dimension (i.e. all sums run from 1 to 1). Also, for clarity, $q=x$ and $p=y$.
$$
[A,B]=A_xB_y-A_yB_x\\
[A,[B,C]]=A_x(B_xC_y-B_yC_x)_y-A_y(B_xC_y-B_yC_x)_x
$$
Therefore,
$$
[A,[B,C]]=A_x(B_{xy}C_{y}+B_xC_{yy}-B_{yy}C_{x}-B_yC_{xy})-A_y(B_{xx}C_{y}+B_xC_{xy}-B_{xy}C_{x}-B_yC_{xx})\\
[B,[C,A]]=B_x(C_{xy}A_{y}+C_xA_{yy}-C_{yy}A_{x}-C_yA_{xy})-B_y(C_{xx}A_{y}+C_xA_{xy}-C_{xy}A_{x}-C_yA_{xx})\\
[C,[A,B]]=C_x(A_{xy}B_{y}+A_xB_{yy}-A_{yy}B_{x}-A_yB_{xy})-C_y(A_{xx}B_{y}+A_xB_{xy}-A_{xy}B_{x}-A_yB_{xx})
$$
By the symmetry of the problem, it will be enough to show that all of the terms multiplying $A_x$ sum to zero. Here is the sum of the terms multiplying $A_x$ from the second and third equations
$$
-B_xC_{yy}+B_yC_{xy}+C_xB_{yy}-C_yB_{xy}\\
=-(B_xC_{yy}-B_yC_{xy}-C_xB_{yy}+C_yB_{xy})\\
=-(B_{xy}C_{y}+B_xC_{yy}-B_{yy}C_{x}-B_yC_{xy})
$$
This is the negative of the terms multiplying $A_x$ in the first equation, so the solution does not depend on $A_x$ since its coefficient is $0$. Checking that the coefficients of $A_y,B_x,B_y, C_x, \text{and} \ C_y$ do in fact sum to zero is easy. Therefore,
$$
[A,[B,C]]+[B,[C,A]]+[C,[A,B]]=0
$$

Comment: THanks, that helps a lot. Some of it was just making sure that certain notations were "allowed" -- I was trying to use the $p_i$ and $q_i$ index notation and the terms weren't canceling, but I also realized it was b/c it was REALLY hard to track. BTW, I was curious if this statement was true: $-\frac{\partial C}{\partial q_i}\frac{\partial^2A}{\partial p_i \partial p_j}\frac{\partial B}{\partial p_i} + \frac{\partial B}{\partial q_i}\frac{\partial C}{\partial p_i}\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial p_j \partial p_i} = 0$. If so, then I had it right the first time :-)

Comment: I was also thinking that it might be possible to set this up as a matrix of some kind since it does look an awful lot like the BAC-CAB rule... but that's probably way too advanced for me.

Comment: As long as you are clear and consistent with your notation, you can generally use any notation you want. Your equation above is not generally zero - just check for the case when $C=q,\ B=p, \text{and}\ A=pp$. Your intuition is correct, there is a way to compress this derivation further with the use of [symplectic matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix). For a graduate level treatment of this derivation using that technique (and which is pretty easy to follow), see "Classical Mechanics" (3rd Ed.) by Goldstein (Ch. 8 & 9).

Comment: I'm not sure - maybe I am missing something -- but if C=q then wouldn't it be $\frac{\partial q}{\partial q_i}$ and $\frac{\partial p}{\partial p_i}$ ? I am not sure what that wold mean, though intuitively it seems that you couldn't "move the numerators" the way you could with ordinary fractions...

Comment: Remember: $\frac{\partial q}{\partial q}=1$ and $\frac{\partial q}{\partial p}=0$, which implies $[q,p]=1$. This means that your above equation when rewritten as $\frac{\partial^2 A}{(\partial p)^2}[B,C]$ is equal to $-1$ when $A=p^2, B=p, \text{and}\ C=q$. (Recall: $[A,B]=-[B,A]\  \therefore\ [p,q]=-1$.)

Comment: What do you mean with symmetry of the problem? You mean that we want to cancel terms? Just like you grouped all the terms which are multiplied by $A_x$ to see if we can cancel with the first parcel of $[A,[B,C]]$?

Comment: @mnp I mean that the problem is symmetrical. If you change all the instances of A to B and vice versa, the equation remains unchanged. The same is true for A to C and B to C. Therefore, whatever holds for one term must hold for the others, so you only have to check one.

Comment: By what argument is it not necessary to show that the coefficient corresponding to $A_y$ also vanishes when doing the sum? Invariance of the sum under cyclic permutation of $A,B,C$ only implies that we do not need to show it for $B_x$ and $C_x$ after it is proven for $A_x$.

Comment: @Christoph90 $[A,B]$ is antisymmetric under exchange of $A$ and $B$, but it is also antisymmetric under exchange of $p$ and $q$. Therefore, $[A,[B,C]]$ is **symmetric** under exchange of $p$ and $q$. In other words, "x" is an arbitrary label for the "first variable of differentiation" in this particular problem -- it could be either $p$ or $q$ as you prefer. Thus, showing the coefficient of $A_x$ is $0$ also shows the same thing for the coefficient of $A_y$. You can easily verify this by inspection.

Comment: @Geoffrey Keen observation - thank you for clarifying!