# Jacobi's identity for bracket product

Tags: differential-geometry

The bracket is:
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
[\cdot,\cdot]:&\mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^n)\times \mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^n)&\longrightarrow &\mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^n)\\
&(X,Y)&\longmapsto &[X,Y]=D_XY-D_YX
\end{array}$$

Let $X,Y,Z\in \mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the Jacobi's identity states that:
$$[X,[Y,Z]]+[Z,[X,Y]]+[Y,[Z,X]]=0$$
If I compute:
$$[X,[Y,Z]]=D_XD_YZ-D_XD_ZY- D_{D_YZ}X+D_{D_ZY}X$$
$$[Z,[X,Y]]=D_ZD_XY-D_ZD_YX-D_{D_XY}Z+D_{D_YX}Z$$
$$[Y,[Z,X]]=D_YD_ZX-D_YD_ZX-D_{D_ZX}Y+D_{D_XZ}Y$$
and do:
$$[X,[Y,Z]]+[Z,[X,Y]]+[Y,[Z,X]]$$
I can't get that the last expresion vanishes.

Can I prove the Jacobi identity by this definition of $[\cdot,\cdot]$?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have $[X,[Y,Z]]=D_X([Y,Z])-D_{[Y,Z]}X=D_X(D_ZY-D_YZ)-D(D_ZY-D_YZ)X=$

$D_X(D_ZY)-D_X(D_YZ)-D^2Z.(X,Y)-D_Z(D_YX+D^2_Y(X,Z)+D_Y(D_Z.X)$

$[X,[Y,Z]]+[Z,[X,Y]]+[Y,[Z,X]]$=

$D_X(D_ZY)-D_X(D_YZ)-D^2Z.(X,Y)-D_Z(D_YX)+D^2Y(X,Z)+D_Y(D_Z.X)$

+$D_Z(D_YX)-D_Z(D_XY)-D^2Y.(Z,X)-D_Y(D_XZ)+D^2X(Z,Y)+D_X(D_Y.Z)$

$D_Y(D_XZ)-D_Y(D_ZX)-D^2X.(Y,Z)-D_X(D_ZY)+D^2Z(Y,X)+D_Z(D_X.Y)=0$

since $D^2X(Y,Z)=D^2X(Z,Y)$.