# Proving Jacobi identity in tensor notation

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

### Context:

In page-233 of Road to Reality, the exterior derivative of a tensor with lower indices is given as;

$$ (d\alpha)_{qr...t}= \partial_{[q} \alpha_{r...t ]}$$

In page-321, Sympletic manifolds are defined as manifold with an anti symmetric upper index tensor field defined on it $S_{ab}$ with the additional property that:

$$dS=0$$

---

In exercise 14.34: An exercise is given to demonstrate the relation that:

$$ \{ \Theta, \{ \Phi, \Psi \} \} + \{ \Phi , \{ \Psi , \Theta \} \} + \{ \Psi , \{ \Theta, \Phi\} \}=0$$

A hint is given to show the following identity first:
$$S^{a[b} \nabla_a S^{cd] }=0$$

This question has been asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754012/jacobis-identity-for-bracket-product?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I want to solve it here index notation. I have so far that,

$$ \{ \Theta, \{ \Phi, \Psi \} \} + \{ \Phi , \{ \Psi , \Theta \} \} + \{ \Psi , \{ \Theta, \Phi\} \}= \text{cyclic perms} \left[  \frac14 S^{ab} \nabla_a \Theta \nabla_b  \left(S^{\eta \nu } \nabla_{\eta} \Phi \nabla_{\nu} \Psi \right) \right]$$

The cyclic perms occur over $\Theta, \psi , \Psi$. I am not sure how to show the hint or proceed after above. BTW I pulled out $S^{\eta \nu}$ by using the metrinillic property mentioned in page 192 of Pavel Grinfeld's Tensor calculus book

Comment: Are you sure he says $S^{ab}$? I highly doubt it.

Comment: Here I don't. Can you quote exactly what is written?

Comment: I've come to mysenses and edited the question @peek-a-boo

Comment: Your Jacobi identity has several typos.

Comment: got confused between psis and phis think it is fixed now @peek-a-boo

Comment: You can't pull the $S$ outside the covariant derivative in the final step.

Comment: The quoted page of the quoted book I say you can do that so I am a bit confused here @peek-a-boo

Comment: I don't know what the text says, either you misunderstood or there's an error in the text (not so likely), but you can't pull it out (because the connection is assumed metric-compatible, not necessarily symplectic-form-compatible).

Comment: It is speaking about surfaes in the book..thought it'd apply here too. Oh well.

Comment: It's not a matter of surfaces or not(i.e not a matter of dimension of the manifold). It is about compatibility of the connection with the tensor fields at hand. We almost always choose the Levi-Civita connection (symplectic-form-compatible connections are not unique).